# .sh file not executing - "xdg-open - opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application"

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

This is my `browser.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! pgrep -x "firefox" > /dev/null
then
    fileFragment=$"*test/html/index.html"
    fullPath=$(find ../ -path $fileFragment)
    xdg-open $fullPath &
fi
```

It works on all other computers except for one at university.
I don't have sudo rights, but neither do I have those at another computer where that works.
The file is executable.
When I try to run it `./browser.sh` I get following output and nothing happens:

```
xdg-open - opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application
Synopsis
xdg-open { file | URL }
xdg-open { --help | --manual | --version }
Use 'man xdg-open' or 'xdg-open --manual' for additional info.
```

Any idea what could be the reason and how to make it run on that pc?

Comment: Are all these computers running the same OS version?

Comment: Presumably the `find` command is failing to find anything, so you are calling `xdg-open` with no file argument. I'm not sure what you're expecting the `$` in front of the string to do, but likely you should be quoting the expansion instead i.e. `find ../ -path "$fileFragment"` to make sure that the `*` expansion is done by `find` itself rather than the shell

Comment: @steeldriver I tried it with `fileFragment="*tams_pour/html/index.html"
 fullPath=$(find ../ -path "$fileFragment")` too now, but no change.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Yes, all are running Ubuntu16.04

Comment: better use something like this `find ../ -path "$fileFragment" -exec xdg-open "{}" \;`

Comment: @Cold_Class you will need to figure out why the file you are looking for isn't in the location where you expect - no one here can do that for you

Comment: @steeldriver So actually your answer is: 'The reason why nothing happens is that the file the script is trying to open is not found'?

Comment: @Cold_Class correct - *one* reason for that *could* have been that `*test/html/index.html` happened to match a file in the current directory (that did not subsequently match anything in `../`) - but the simpler one is that no such file(s) exist on the specific PC